# Gson parsing problems, null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, json, gson

This is the format of the JSON as configured in the API:

```
{  
"Hotels":[  
  {  
     "EANHotelID":"257219",
     "Country":"IN",
     "Name":"Toshali Sands Ethnic Village Resort",
     "LowRate":"88.32",
     "HighRate":"118.77",
     "Latitude":"19.83861",
     "Longitude":"85.89400",
     "Location":"Near the bay",
     "PostalCode":"752002",
     "PropertyCategory":"3",
     "PropertyCurrency":"INR",
     "StarRating":"4.0",
     "StateProvince":"",
     "CheckInTime":"10 AM",
     "CheckOutTime":"8 AM",
     "City":"Puri",
     "Confidence":"52",
     "AirportCode":"BBI",
     "Caption":"Featured Image",
     "ThumbnailURL":"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/2000000/1720000/1710100/1710078/1710078_35_t.jpg",
     "URL":"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/2000000/1720000/1710100/1710078/1710078_35_b.jpg"
  },
  {  
     "EANHotelID":"397792",
     "Country":"IN",
     "Name":"MAYFAIR Heritage, Puri",
     "LowRate":"138.8325",
     "HighRate":"176.55",
     "Latitude":"19.79851",
     "Longitude":"85.83413",
     "Location":"Near Puri Beach",
     "PostalCode":"752002",
     "PropertyCategory":"1",
     "PropertyCurrency":"INR",
     "StarRating":"4.0",
     "StateProvince":"",
     "CheckInTime":"8 AM",
     "CheckOutTime":"8 AM",
     "City":"Puri",
     "Confidence":"60",
     "AirportCode":"BBI",
     "Caption":"Featured Image",
     "ThumbnailURL":"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/5000000/4790000/4780200/4780106/4780106_20_t.jpg",
     "URL":"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/5000000/4790000/4780200/4780106/4780106_20_b.jpg"
  },
  {  
     "EANHotelID":"397792",
     "Country":"IN",
     "Name":"MAYFAIR Heritage, Puri",
     "LowRate":"138.8325",
     "HighRate":"176.55",
     "Latitude":"19.79851",
     "Longitude":"85.83413",
     "Location":"Near Puri Beach",
     "PostalCode":"752002",
     "PropertyCategory":"1",
     "PropertyCurrency":"INR",
     "StarRating":"4.0",
     "StateProvince":"",
     "CheckInTime":"8 AM",
     "CheckOutTime":"8 AM",
     "City":"Puri",
     "Confidence":"60",
     "AirportCode":"BBI",
     "Caption":"Featured Image",
     "ThumbnailURL":"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/5000000/4790000/4780200/4780106/4780106_20_t.jpg",
     "URL":"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/5000000/4790000/4780200/4780106/4780106_20_b.jpg"
  }
  ]
  }
```

And these are the model classes I have used for parsing the json using GSON

hotel_list.java

```
public class hotel_list {
@SerializedName("Hotels")
@Expose
public ArrayList<hotel> hotel_list;

public ArrayList<hotel> getHotel_list() { return hotel_list;}

public void setHotel_list(ArrayList<hotel> hotel_list) {
    this.hotel_list = hotel_list;
}
}
```

hotel.java

```
public class hotel {



@SerializedName("EANHotelID")
@Expose

private String EANHotelID;

@SerializedName("Country")
@Expose
private String Country;

@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
private String Name;

@SerializedName("LowRate")
@Expose
private String LowRate;

@SerializedName("HighRate")
@Expose
private String HighRate;

@SerializedName("Latitude")
@Expose
private String Latitude;

@SerializedName("Longitude")
@Expose
private String Longitude;

@SerializedName("Location")
@Expose
private String Location;

@SerializedName("PostalCode")
@Expose
private String PostalCode;

@SerializedName("PropertyCategory")
@Expose
private String PropertyCategory;

@SerializedName("PropertyCurrency")
@Expose
private String PropertyCurrency;

@SerializedName("StarRating")
@Expose
private String StarRating;

@SerializedName("StateProvince")
@Expose
private String StateProvince;

@SerializedName("CheckInTime")
@Expose
private String CheckInTime;

@SerializedName("CheckOutTime")
@Expose
private String CheckOutTime;

@SerializedName("City")
@Expose
private String City;

@SerializedName("Confidence")
@Expose
private String Confidence;

@SerializedName("AirportCode")
@Expose
private String AirportCode;

@SerializedName("Caption")
@Expose
private String Caption;

@SerializedName("ThumbnailURL")
@Expose
private String ThumbnailURL;

@SerializedName("URL")
@Expose
private String URL;


public String getEANHotelID() {
    return EANHotelID;
}

public void setEANHotelID(String EANHotelID) {
    this.EANHotelID = EANHotelID;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return Country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    Country = country;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getLowRate() {
    return LowRate;
}

public void setLowRate(String lowRate) {
    LowRate = lowRate;
}

public String getHighRate() {
    return HighRate;
}

public void setHighRate(String highRate) {
    HighRate = highRate;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return Latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    Latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return Longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    Longitude = longitude;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return Location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    Location = location;
}

public String getPostalCode() {
    return PostalCode;
}

public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
    PostalCode = postalCode;
}

public String getPropertyCategory() {
    return PropertyCategory;
}

public void setPropertyCategory(String propertyCategory) {
    PropertyCategory = propertyCategory;
}

public String getPropertyCurrency() {
    return PropertyCurrency;
}

public void setPropertyCurrency(String propertyCurrency) {
    PropertyCurrency = propertyCurrency;
}

public String getStarRating() {
    return StarRating;
}

public void setStarRating(String starRating) {
    StarRating = starRating;
}

public String getStateProvince() {
    return StateProvince;
}

public void setStateProvince(String stateProvince) {
    StateProvince = stateProvince;
}

public String getCheckInTime() {
    return CheckInTime;
}

public void setCheckInTime(String checkInTime) {
    CheckInTime = checkInTime;
}

public String getCheckOutTime() {
    return CheckOutTime;
}

public void setCheckOutTime(String checkOutTime) {
    CheckOutTime = checkOutTime;
}

public String getCity() {
    return City;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    City = city;
}

public String getConfidence() {
    return Confidence;
}

public void setConfidence(String confidence) {
    Confidence = confidence;
}

public String getAirportCode() {
    return AirportCode;
}

public void setAirportCode(String airportCode) {
    AirportCode = airportCode;
}

public String getCaption() {
    return Caption;
}

public void setCaption(String caption) {
    Caption = caption;
}

public String getThumbnailURL() {
    return ThumbnailURL;
}

public void setThumbnailURL(String thumbnailURL) {
    ThumbnailURL = thumbnailURL;
}

public String getURL() {
    return URL;
}

public void setURL(String URL) {
    this.URL = URL;
}
}
```

And this is the AsyncTask doInBackground method which fetches the json and tries to parse it.

doInBackground

```
@Override
    protected hotel_list doInBackground(Void... params) {

        hotel_list hotelList = new hotel_list();

        try {
            //Create an HTTP client
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet post = new HttpGet(url);


            //Perform the request and check the status code
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);


            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            Log.e(REST, Integer.toString(statusLine.getStatusCode()));
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();




                try {
                    //Read the server response and attempt to parse it as JSON

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                    // Log.e(TAG, reader.readLine());
                    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                    gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
                    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                    String str=reader.readLine();
                    Log.i("json object",str);
                    hotelList = gson.fromJson(reader, hotel_list.class);

                    content.close();






                    //   handlePostsList(posts);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(REST, "Failed to parse JSON due to: " + ex);

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(REST, "Server responded with status code: " + statusLine.getStatusCode());

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(REST, "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: " + ex);

        }
        Log.i("list",hotelList.getHotel_list().get(1).getName());
        return hotelList;
    }
```

Now the problem is that the hotelList being returned is null. GSON is not showing any errors but the parsed contents are not getting filled in the list and it remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

Logcat message -

```
09-23 01:42:52.374    1950-1963/com.neelraj.hotels W/art﹕ Suspending all      threads took: 25.899ms
09-23 01:42:54.321    1950-1995/com.neelraj.hotels I/json object﹕ " {\"Hotels\":[{\"EANHotelID\":\"176933\",\"Country\":\"IN\",\"Name\":\"The Park  Kolkata\",\"LowRate\":\"76.13\",\"HighRate\":\"226.5\",\"Latitude\":\"22.55409\",\"Longitude\":\"88.35143\",\"Location\":\"Near New Market\",\"PostalCode\":\"700016\",\"PropertyCategory\":\"1\",\"PropertyCurrency\":\"INR\",\"StarRating\":\"5.0\",\"StateProvince\":\"\",\"CheckInTime\":\"2 PM\",\"CheckOutTime\":\"noon\",\"City\":\"Kolkata\",\"Confidence\":\"52\",\"AirportCode\":\"CCU\",\"Caption\":\"Featured Image\",\"ThumbnailURL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/1000000/530000/523000/522928/522928_33_t.jpg\",\"URL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/1000000/530000/523000/522928/522928_33_b.jpg\"},{\"EANHotelID\":\"185519\",\"Country\":\"IN\",\"Name\":\"The Peerless Inn - Kolkata\",\"LowRate\":\"91.36\",\"HighRate\":\"137.04\",\"Latitude\":\"22.56217\",\"Longitude\":\"88.35157\",\"Location\":\"Near New Market\",\"PostalCode\":\"700 013\",\"PropertyCategory\":\"1\",\"PropertyCurrency\":\"INR\",\"StarRating\":\"4.0\",\"StateProvince\":\"\",\"CheckInTime\":\"noon\",\"CheckOutTime\":\"noon\",\"City\":\"Kolkata\",\"Confidence\":\"52\",\"AirportCode\":\"CCU\",\"Caption\":\"Featured Image\",\"ThumbnailURL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/2000000/1070000/1066400/1066383/1066383_13_t.jpg\",\"URL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/2000000/1070000/1066400/1066383/1066383_13_b.jpg\"},{\"EANHotelID\":\"516167\",\"Country\":\"IN\",\"Name\":\"Hotel O2 VIP\",\"LowRate\":\"56.32\",\"HighRate\":\"71.55\",\"Latitude\":\"22.63360\",\"Longitude\":\"88.43468\",\"Location\":\"In Kolkata (Dum Dum)\",\"PostalCode\":\"700052\",\"PropertyCategory\":\"1\",\"PropertyCurrency\":\"INR\",\"StarRating\":\"3.0\",\"StateProvince\":\"\",\"CheckInTime\":\"\",\"CheckOutTime\":\"noon\",\"City\":\"kolkata\",\"Confidence\":\"\",\"AirportCode\":\"CCU\",\"Caption\":\"Featured Image\",\"ThumbnailURL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/12000000/11040000/11032100/11032008/11032008_3_t.jpg\",\"URL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/12000000/11040000/11032100/11032008/11032008_3_b.jpg\"},{\"EANHotelID\":\"198401\",\"Country\":\"IN\",\"Name\":\"Taj Bengal\",\"LowRate\":\"192.7119\",\"HighRate\":\"859.6464\",\"Latitude\":\"22.53706\",\"Longitude\":\"88.33366\",\"Location\":\"Near Alipore Zoo\",\"PostalCode\":\"700 027\",\"PropertyCategory\":\"1\",\"PropertyCurrency\":\"INR\",\"StarRating\":\"5.0\",\"StateProvince\":\"\",\"CheckInTime\":\"2 PM\",\"CheckOutTime\":\"Noon\",\"City\":\"Kolkata\",\"Confidence\":\"95\",\"AirportCode\":\"CCU\",\"Caption\":\"Featured Image\",\"ThumbnailURL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/1000000/470000/465100/465007/465007_77_t.jpg\",\"URL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/1000000/470000/465100/465007/465007_77_b.jpg\"},{\"EANHotelID\":\"215054\",\"Country\":\"IN\",\"Name\":\"ITC Sonar Kolkata\",\"LowRate\":\"174.9995\",\"HighRate\":\"221.9965\",\"Latitude\":\"22.54331\",\"Longitude\":\"88.39665\",\"Location\":\"Near Science City\",\"PostalCode\":\"700046\",\"PropertyCategory\":\"1\",\"PropertyCurrency\":\"INR\",\"StarRating\":\"5.0\",\"StateProvince\":\"\",\"CheckInTime\":\"2 PM\",\"CheckOutTime\":\"\",\"City\":\"Kolkata\",\"Confidence\":\"52\",\"AirportCode\":\"CCU\",\"Caption\":\"Featured Image\",\"ThumbnailURL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/1000000/930000/922100/922011/922011_66_t.jpg\",\"URL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/1000000/930000/922100/922011/922011_66_b.jpg\"},{\"EANHotelID\":\"219474\",\"Country\":\"IN\",\"Name\":\"Golden Parkk\",\"LowRate\":\"78.57\",\"HighRate\":\"126.9\",\"Latitude\":\"22.54741\",\"Longitude\":\"88.34966\",\"Location\":\"Near Victoria Memorial\",\"PostalCode\":\"700071\",\"PropertyCategory\":\"1\",\"PropertyCurrency\":\"INR\",\"StarRating\":\"3.0\",\"StateProvince\":\"\",\"CheckInTime\":\"3 PM\",\"CheckOutTime\":\"noon\",\"City\":\"Kolkata\",\"Confidence\":\"52\",\"AirportCode\":\"CCU\",\"Caption\":\"Featured Image\",\"ThumbnailURL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/2000000/1060000/1056000/1055970/1055970_41_t.jpg\",\"URL\":\"http://media.expedia.com/hotels/2000000/1060000/105
  09-23 01:42:54.344    1950-1995/com.neelraj.hotels E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.neelraj.hotels, PID: 1950
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.neelraj.hotels.model.hotel_list.getHotel_list()' on a null object reference
        at com.neelraj.hotels.MainActivity$Fetch.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:153)
        at com.neelraj.hotels.MainActivity$Fetch.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:84)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to the minimum amount of code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: also, show your logcat, please.

Comment: Tip: if you can run your single line of JSON through a formatter, it's much easier for folks to grok it. There are JSON formatters on the web, e.g. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Comment: Is the API under your control? If so, look at your web server logs to see if a request is received.

Comment: @halfer Yes, the api is under my control and the response json is coming in the reader. it's just not parsing

Comment: @halfer formatted the json. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are read your data out of your input stream into a string, and then passing that input stream to your JSON parsing routine.  It is already at the end of the file, so it reads an empty input which is not objects/arrays and returns null.  You should either remove the following lines--

```
String str=reader.readLine();
Log.i("json object",str);
```

OR pass in the string you already read --

```
hotelList = gson.fromJson(str, hotel_list.class);  //pass str instead of reader
```

I would recommend not pre-reading into a string because it is going to be more efficient and handle multiple line files.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change generic list type to simple array:

`public ArrayList<hotel> hotel_list;`

to:

`public hotel[] hotel_list;`

and

`Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();`

to:

`Gson gson = new Gson();`

Comment: Changing into a simple array didn't work. It still doesn't parse

Answer (score 1):

problem could be this:

`hotelList = gson.fromJson(reader, hotel_list.class);`

change to:

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 String aux = "";

 while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     builder.append(aux);
 }

hotelList = gson.fromJson(builder.toString(), hotel_list.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to use the following:
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org 
Find what you need and then try it out in your app.
Also the name of the class should be capital.
**EDIT** 
If using List doesn't work try as in the following example:
http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON

Here they do using the arrays([]).

Comment: The pojo I have was generated using the same